# php: preg_match failed with special character pattern

Tags: php, regex

I have an issue with php regex. I have same regex in JS and it works. I don't know what is the problem.

this is the php code regex:

```
echo $password; // 9Gq!Q23Lne;<||.'/\
$reg_password = "/^[-_0-9a-záàâäãåçéèêëíìîïñóòôöõúùûüýÿæœÁÀÂÄÃÅÇÉÈÊËÍÌÎÏÑÓÒÔÖÕÚÙÛÜÝŸÆŒ0\d!@#$%^&*()_\+\{\}:\"<>?\|\[\];\',\.\/\x5c~]{6,30}$/i";
if(isset($password) &&
  (!preg_match($reg_password, $password) || !preg_match("#[a-z]#", $password) || !preg_match("#[\d]#", $password))
){
   echo "you failed";
 }
```

original password from html input:

```
9Gq!Q23Lne;<||.\'/\
```

it is the same value just before the $reg_password.

I have make a test using escape_string from mysqli method but it doesn't work too:

```
$password = $this->db->escape_string($password);
echo $password; // 9Gq!Q23Lne;<||.\'/\\
```

I don't know what is my problem because I have used [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) to test it and it works..

Any idea about that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call `preg_match` multiple times, just use lookahead to enforce your rules as in this regex:

```
^(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[a-z])[-\wáàâäãåçéèêëíìîïñóòôöõúùûüýÿæœÁÀÂÄÃÅÇÉÈÊËÍÌÎÏÑÓÒÔÖÕÚÙÛÜÝŸÆŒ0\d!@#$%^&*()+{}:"<>?|\[\];',./\x5c~]{6,30}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sL5iD3/1)

**Code:**

```
$re = "`^(?=.*?\\d)(?=.*?[a-z])[-\\wáàâäãåçéèêëíìîïñóòôöõúùûüýÿæœÁÀÂÄÃÅÇÉÈÊËÍÌÎÏÑÓÒÔÖÕÚÙÛÜÝŸÆŒ0\\d!@#$%^&*()+{}:\"<>?|\\[\\];',./\\x5c~]{6,30}$`mu";
$str = "9Gq!Q23Lne;<||.\'/\\"; 

if (!preg_match($re, $input)) {
   echo "you failed";
}
```

Comment: ho nice.. I'll try to learn about this. bug fixed! just to know: need to double backslash like your example? \\w \\d \\[ \\] ... ?

Comment: You can also use: `$re = '\`^(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[a-z])[-\wáàâäãåçéèêëíìîïñóòôöõúùûüýÿæœÁÀÂÄÃÅÇÉÈÊËÍÌÎÏÑÓÒÔÖÕÚÙÛÜÝŸÆŒ0\\d!@#$%^&*()+{}:"<>?|\[\];\',./\x5c~]{6,30}$\`mu';`

Comment: I have no idea why it got down-voted. Probably someone didn't like my suggestion of using single `preg_match` instead of 3

Answer (score 2):

In your pattern, you need to use single quote instead of double ;)

So it will be like this

```
$reg_password = '/^[-_0-9a-záàâäãåçéèêëíìîïñóòôöõúùûüýÿæœÁÀÂÄÃÅÇÉÈÊËÍÌÎÏÑÓÒÔÖÕÚÙÛÜÝŸÆŒ0\d!@#$%^&*()_\+\{\}:\"<>?\|\[\];\',\.\/\x5c~]{6,30}$/i';
```

Comment: true too! i try and it works fine too! I need to compare with me. Hate to make the same error twice.

Comment: Most of the special characters don't need escaping inside a character class.